# Add Webpack Alias With react-app-rewired and customize-cra

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am trying to reduce the size of the [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) library by eliminating unnecessary icons. I found this solution online, https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011#issuecomment-423173228

The solution involves configuring Webpack like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/icons.js")
    }
  }
};
```

I don't know how to do this because I am using `react-app-rewired` and `customize-cra` along with `babel-plugin-import`, so my "config-overrides.js" file looks like this, which is very different from the provided example.

```
const { override, fixBabelImports } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    fixBabelImports('import', {
        libraryName: 'antd',
        style: 'css',
    }),
);
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
"antd": "^3.14.1",
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
"customize-cra": "^0.2.12",
"downshift": "^3.2.6",
"material-icons-react": "^1.0.4",
"react": "^16.8.3",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.1.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.3",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
"styled-components": "^4.1.3"
```

This looks very different from the example in the Github Issue. How do I add an alias to my "config-overrides.js" file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use plugin `addWebpackAlias` of `customize-cra`

```
/* global require, module, __dirname */
const { override, fixBabelImports, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: 'css',
  }),
  addWebpackAlias({
    ['@']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  })
)
```

Comment: How to add **UglifyJsPlugin** in **customize-cra** .

Ex: `const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
};`

Comment: This definitely solved my problem. Thanks!