# tsconfig.json using alias for import not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, alias, tsconfig

I have project with react ts.
Recently I try to use alias for my imports.
So for that I have edit my file tsconfig.json with this params :

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFOIq.png)

and I change my path import in my file like so :

```js
import { couleurQualite } from "../../utils/coloration";
```

to

```js
import { couleurQualite } from "@utils/coloration";
```

When I move my cursor on import my IDE show that :
[IDE resolution path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMn4E.png)

So at this place I don't have any error.
But when i start my projet with cmd : npm run start

I receive these errors

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@utils/coloration' in '/home/YYYY/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/src/components/items'

ERROR in ./src/components/items/ItemBadge.tsx 11:0-51

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@utils/coloration' in '/home/YYYY/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/src/components/items'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

This is my project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAsny.png)

Someone can help me ?

Comment: not sure if this is solves the issue, but your project root path is quite long and contains special chars (e.g. `../Font-main(1)/..`. try to move it to a shorter path that does not contain special chars

Comment: Thank for your reply, I have this project on other computer, where the path is more short and not contains special chars. And I have same issu. Indeed, IDE have not problems for find file import.I think  it's the compiler that can't find the path, as can be seen on the error. He ignore aliases, but I don’t know how to tell him to take them into account

Comment: Just saw that the error mentions webpack - so I guess that the typescript compiler is not the problem - you must also somehow tell webpack to understand the path-mappings: maybe this blog helps: https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2018/08/21/typescript-webpack-alias-goodbye-relative-paths

Comment: I think `"baseUrl": "./src",` will resolve your issue since all your files are under `src` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it working, thank @TmTrom your answer put me on the right way.

Some precision :
with create-react-app, I can't directly edit webpack.config.js, so I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992493/add-webpack-alias-with-react-app-rewired-and-customize-cra) for have same result.

1. add required module
2. create config-overrides.js and add to it information :

```
addWebpackAlias({
        ['@customName']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/directory')
    })
```

you can also try [this](https://plusreturn.com/blog/how-to-configure-a-path-alias-in-a-react-typescript-app-for-cleaner-imports/) for rewrite webpack

The two cases work for me

EDIT :
You can also edit file webpack.config.js, he is located :
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

And in this option, you don't need install any other module.